# WhatsApp is getting downloaded but not getting installed

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, installation

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running on Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean. It had a problem with restarting by itself. As it restarted too many times at a stretch, it did a factory reset on its own. It did not delete any music or image file, but all the apps got uninstalled.

I successfully reinstalled all apps, *except WhatsApp*. WhatsApp was getting downloaded but it was not getting installed. I don't know why. I tried downloading it from Play Store and an app called Mobogenie. I even tried using ShareIt. The app is still not getting installed.

How to fix this and reinstall WhatsApp?

Comment: A phone should not factory reset itself. does your phone have enough free space. Also use Avast and do a virus scan

Answer (score 1):

Download WhatsApp manually from apkmirror.com and try to install using that apk file and reason for your device getting restarted own its own can be the too many apps and phone ram not able to handle them properly and too many restarts (due to ram issue ) can cause reset